# Чтение двух чисел из файла и вывод их суммы в другой файл на Python

Tags: python

Даны два числа A и B. Вам нужно вычислить их сумму A+B. В этой задаче вам нужно читать из файла и выводить ответ в файл

**Формат ввода**

Первая строка входного файла содержит числа A и B, разделенные пробелом

**Формат вывода**

В единственной строке выходного файла выведите сумму чисел A+

*Ввод* input.txt

*Вывод* output.txt

**На Python**!!!

Comment: За 500 рублей сделаю

Comment: @markrefox Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
def main():
    with open('input.txt') as f:
        nums = f.read().split()

    a, b = map(int, nums)
    result = a + b

    with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(str(result))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```